# AWS Session Manager is not sourcing bash rc

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I am using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to connect to my EC2 instance.

When I connect, the session does not source my .bashrc or .bash_profile, so I get a pretty plain shell and would like to setup some configuration when it starts.

The session manager connects me as the ec2-user but the shell starts in the / directory and not the user directory.

I am unable to figure out if it is sourcing any configuration files when it starts up.
How can I get it to source the users configuration files?

I have set up session manager to use the ec2-user by enabling the "run as support" setting.

If I connect to an instance using the EC2 instance connect then it works as you can see here: 
[image: EC2 instance connect with sourced files]

However if I use the session manager, the configuration files are not sourced as you can see here:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**AWS Systems Manager Session Manager** uses an "agent" to establish a connection with the Amazon EC2 instance. The agent registers the instance with Systems Manager. When a connection is requested, a message is sent to the agent. Commands are then sent to the agent, which executes them locally and sends back the results.

Therefore, Session Manager is not actually logged into a bash session. It is simply executing the commands one-at-a-time as received.

The benefit of Session Manager is that it can be used to connect to a private EC2 instance because the agent establishes an 'outbound' connection to AWS, rather than the connection request being sent 'to' the instance.

**Amazon EC2 Instance Connect**, in contrast, actually establishes a normal SSH connection to the instance. The web browser uses a Guacamole connection to AWS, which then uses normal SSH (with an extra hack to permit temporary keypairs) to run the commands. Therefore, it looks like a normal connection running against the shell.

You can actually use the "temporary SSH keys" feature of EC2 Instance Connect together with a normal SSH client, without using the web-based SSH client. Thus, it's actually two features in one: a web-based SSH client, and a means of using temporary keypairs to establish the SSH connection.

Comment: Thanks John, that explains it. I tested, and as expected from your answer, this also means that you cannot use Instance Connect if SSH ports are not open on the security group.

Comment: Correct. The security group needs to permit inbound SSH from the ranges of the EC2 Instance Connect service (not your own IP address).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because by default you are logged as [ssm-user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-ssm-user-permissions.html), not `ec2-user`. Thus to log in as `ec2-user` you can execute the following command:

```
sudo su - ec2-user
```

This will login you as `ec2-user`, source your `.bashrc` and place you in `/home/ec2-user`.

Alternatively, if you use `EC2 Instance connect`, `ec2-user` is specify as default and it **correctly loads** you into `/home/ec2-user` and sources your bash.

[image: <code>/home/ec2-user</code>]

[image]

Comment: I changed session manager to log in in as ec2-user using the "Run As support" preference. So if I run ´whoami´ right after I connect it tells me that I am "ec2-user"

Comment: @morras Thanks for letting me know. So it works now?

Comment: No that is the problem. Even though it logs me in as ec2-user it does not source any of my configuration files. If I afterwards source them manually or run `bash` then it works correctly. But why does it not source the configuration files by it self?

Comment: @morras I see what you mean now. I will try to spin up an instance and check the behavior.

Comment: @morras I verified the login and had no issues. Please check my extended answer.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin I tested out your approach, and if I use EC2 Instance Connect then the configuration files are sourced, but if I use session manager they are not. I have updated my question with this information and screenshots.
I will raise this with AWS support as that might just be a missing feature.

Answer (score -1):

As Session Manager is not actually logged into a bash session, but we can do that by creating a custom InteractiveCommands session document that will just switch to ssm-user bash. The steps are below.

1. Create AWS SSM document "session" type named "SSM-LogLinuxBash" and paste the below content.

> ```
>    {
>       "schemaVersion": "1.0",
>       "description": "Document to run single interactive command on an instance",
>       "sessionType": "InteractiveCommands",
>       "parameters": {
>         "logpath": {
>           "type": "String",
>           "description": "Logged in as bash shell",
>           "default": "",
>           "allowedPattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+(.log)$"
>         }
>       },
>       "properties": {
>         "linux": {
>           "commands": "su ssm-user",
>           "runAsElevated": true
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

2. Create IAM policy that can access the above SSM document and ec2 instance.

> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "SSM-LogLinuxBash-IAMPolicy",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Action": "ssm:StartSession",
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/SSM-LogLinuxBash",
>                 "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/<instanceid>or*"
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "Sid": "TerminateSSM Session",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Action": "ssm:TerminateSession",
>             "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/${aws:username}-*"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

3. Attach policy to IAM group or IAM user.
4. Access the instance

> ```
> aws ssm start-session --target <instance-id-here> --document-name SSM-LogLinuxBash
> ```

For details please go through the below blog.
[For complete implementation](https://sudhanshudev3.medium.com/how-to-logged-into-a-linux-bash-session-using-aws-system-manager-session-manager-1a5d5659de87)

Comment: Sudhanshu Dev, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Sure will do that.