# AWS Session manager welcome message

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I have noticed that .bashrc does not run whenever launching an AWS session in Systems manager session manager.. Switching user using su - user however does run .bashrc but that is not what I am trying to achieve.

My objective is to have a welcome message whenever someone starts a session through the console/browser.

Does anyone have any work around or ideas on how to do this? /etc/motd didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the **limitations** of SSM Session Manager reported in several places, e.g.:

- [SSM Session Manager does not source .bashrc or .bash_profile](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=293309)
- [Custom Shell for `aws ssm start-session`](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/131)
- [AWS Session Manager is not sourcing bash rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211608/aws-session-manager-is-not-sourcing-bash-rc)

You can only **customize for now the user** which ssm agent is using. So instead of `ssm-user` you can [change](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-preferences-run-as.html) it to `ec2-user` or based on your individual IAM users.

You could also consider using [EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) instead of `Session Manager`. The connect works as expected, though its not enabled by default on Ubuntu.